# Firestore query does not return results when I start sorting by Timestamp

Tags: android, google-cloud-firestore

I have a query that looks like this:

```
Query mealplanQuery = firebaseFirestore.collection("Meal_Plans").whereEqualTo("userId", userId);
```

And this works fine. Gives me all of the results I am looking for.

However I have another field in the document called *orderDate* which is a timestamp. And I need to sort the results in a descending order by this timestamp field. So as soon as I append that to the query, I am not getting any results.

So all I am doing is this:

```
Query mealplanQuery = firebaseFirestore.collection("Meal_Plans").whereEqualTo("userId", userId).orderBy("orderDate", Query.Direction.DESCENDING);
```

Any idea why I am not getting any results.

Comment: You don't get any results because you did **not** create an index. Please check the duplicate to see how you can solve this issue.

Comment: Hi Alex - I checked under Indexes and an index is created. It looks like "orderDate Descending userId Ascending".

Comment: As I see in your code, you aren't ordering by `userId` ascending, you are only ordering by `orderDate` ascending. So you should create the correct index.

Comment: @BVB09 If the problem is with the index, there will be a message in your logcat output of the format in the question that Alex linked. If there is no such message, the problem is not caused by a missing index.

Comment: Frank, any idea what it could be? If I query with the parameters individually then I am able to get results and they are accurate. But as soon as I combine them then it fails. I did setup the indexes in the console but they were done manually i.e. I was not prompted from logcat.